# add to value of input instead of overwrite val

Tags: jquery, append

This is my code

```
$('#enterTags').keydown(function(event) {
                var tag = $(this).val();
                // 188 is comma, 13 is enter
                if (event.which === 188 || event.which === 13) {
                    if (tag) {
                        $('#tags').append('<div>' + tag + '</div>');
                        **$('#falseInput').val(tag + ', ');**
                        $(this).val('');
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                // 8 is backspace
                else if (event.which == 8) {
                    if (!tag) {
                        $('#tags div:last').remove();
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The section of code I bolded is what I am having problems with.  I need the value of #enterTags to be added to that of #falseInput, not overwrite it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#falseInput').val($('#falseInput').val() + tag + ', ');
```

or:

```
$('#falseInput').val(function(index, value) {
  return value + tag + ', ';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#falseInput').val($('#falseInput').val() + ', ' + tag);
```